# How to pass a value from one Fragment to another in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I am a newbie to Fragments. I want to pass a String value from one Fragment to another. how to do this? I have called my Fragments in the following way. please guide me step by step.

```
String cid = id.getText().toString();
Fragment fr = new FriendFragment();
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do something like below,

```
 String cid=id.getText().toString();
 Fragment fr=new friendfragment();
 FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
 android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("CID", cid);
 fr.setArguments(args);
 ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
 ft.commit();
```

To receive the data do the following,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("CID");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: How to receive it at the other fragment?

Comment: This creates leakages if the data is huge, instead you should use the interface design pattern for communication between fragments.

Comment: In the line :  String cid=id.getText().toString();  what is meant by 'Id'? I have string array. from there how to use 'Id'. Plz help

Answer (score 6):

If you want to send data from fragment to activity you may use an interface.

But when you want to send data from fragment to another fragment it get's complicated. You would want to send data to activity and then to the other fragment.

I use [**EventBus**](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/) to solve this problem.
How it works.

1. Create an event-E.
2. From Fragment-A register for events.
3. From fragment-B publish event-E with data you want to pass.
4. You would get the data in onEvent() method you wrote in Fragment-A.

That's it. No need to write your own interfaces.

You may use eventbus for communications from background service or threads to activity also.

Checkout the [EventBus HowTo](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md) and [Repository](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) also.

Comment: Can I ask you to review the follow post please? [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Answer (score 0):

Fragment to Fragment communication must be done through the parent Activity.

**FragmentToSendData**

```
interface <interfaceName>{
    void <abstract method>(String str);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
       try{
           <instance of the interface> = (<interface>)getActivity();
       }catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                   + " must implement <interface>");
       }

    }
```

**ActivityWithBothFragments** (this can be through ViewPager, or use the id of your fragment, just use findFragmentById() )

```
@Override <abstract method from frag1>(String str){
  FragmentToReceiveData fragment2 =  (FragmentToReceiveData)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ViewPagerAdapter.getFragmentTag(1));                                                                                                                                                

    fragment2.getStringFromFrag1(String str);
}
```

**FragmentToReceiveData**

```
public void getStringFromFrag1(String str){
  <textview>.setText("str");

}
```

Comment: Isn't it needed to clear the <instance of the interface> on onDetach()?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :

- send data : 

        Bundle arg = new Bundle();
        arg.putInt("ID", "12");  //arg.putInt("KEY", "VALUE")
        arg.putString("NAME","Jaydeep");//arg.putString("KEY","VALUE")

        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arg);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add("PUT YOUR FRAM ID", fragment, fragment.getClass().getName())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();

- receive data : 

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        bundle.getInt("ID");
        bundle.getString("NAME");

        Log.e("Receive data : " ,"\nID - "+bundle.getInt("ID")+"\nNAME - "+bundle.getString("NAME"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

First Fragment

```
//adding data to the bundle class
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("user_name","simon");
b.putString("user_address","nepal");
//fragment operation
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment=new friendfragment();
fragment.setArguments(b);
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();

//Second Fragment(Receiving Fragment)
//write following code into onCreateView() method
Bundle b = getArguments();
String name = b.getString("user_name");
String address = b.getString("user_address");
```