# getting all views value in all fragment ViewPager from activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

i would like to ask, is it possible to get all the views values from all my fragments(currently i have 3 fragment which connected using ViewPager) from activity views when i pressed submit button from my activity?

Comment: Refer to this link, it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23250795/9346054

Comment: @Zuhrain so by you means that each time i have switch the tabs of the pager i have to pass value from one fragment to other fragment until i stop at the visible fragment and get all the value from that visible fragment? Is there any possibilities get value directly from activities without passing value from each fragment?